# How to syntax check a cassandra cql file from command line before executing it?

Tags: cassandra, cql, syntax-checking

During development of cassandra datamodel how to very quickly do a commandline syntax check before executing the commands using cqlsh to avoid unnecessary troubleshooting? The larger the cql the more valuable the syntax check is.

Comment: I would suggest going to cassandra mailing list for this one, this might even becomme some feature request. Sometimes Dev Center dosn't really help. Most of the cassandra related apps leave this directly to cassandra i.e. https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/interpreter/cassandra.html - section about Syntax Validation

Answer (score 1):

try DevCenter from DataStax, it's free and I think it works on both non-DSE and DSE platforms

Comment: sounds interesting